# Get XML from my SELECT on the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have the following xml

```
declare @Obligaciones xml 
set @Obligaciones = '<obligaciones>
  <Obligacion id = "51" TipoCancelacionObligacionId = "1" > </Obligacion>
  <Obligacion id = "52" TipoCancelacionObligacionId = "2"> </Obligacion>
  <Obligacion id = "53" TipoCancelacionObligacionId = "2"> </Obligacion>
  </obligaciones>'
```

I would like to get the following as the result of my query

```
<obligaciones>
  <Obligacion id = "51" TipoCancelacionObligacionId = "1" > </Obligacion>
</obligaciones>
```

Can sombody help with the query?
I been trying for a while without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT  
    @Obligaciones.query('/obligaciones/Obligacion[@id="51"]')
FOR XML PATH (''),ROOT('obligaciones')
```

Gives me the desired output:

```
<obligaciones>
  <Obligacion id="51" TipoCancelacionObligacionId="1" />
</obligaciones>
```

The `@Obligaciones.query()` fetches the XML element with the `id=51` attribute, and then I wrap the resulting line of XML into a XML root element called `<obligaciones>`.

**Update:** if you're looking to get the **first** element regardless of its `id` attribute - use this query instead:

```
SELECT  
    @Obligaciones.query('/obligaciones/Obligacion[1]')
FOR XML PATH (''),ROOT('obligaciones')
```

Comment: I suspect Hugo wants the first element, not the one with a specific ID.

Comment: Looks good. The first one *might* be right, but I doubt that `51` is always the sought-after element.